# Why exception is printed in the end on the console while running below java code

Tags: java, exception

In my way to learn exception handling in java I've encountered unusual behavior of exceptions to be printed on console.

Java Code:

```
public class ExceptionHandlingRunner2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method1();
        System.out.println("Main Ended");
    }

    private static void method1(){
       method2();
        System.out.println("Method1() Ended");
    }

    private static void method2() {
        try{
            String str = null;
            str.length();
            System.out.println("Method2 ended");
        } catch (NullPointerException ex){
            System.out.println("in catch NullPointerException");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("in catch Exception");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output after trying to **Debug**

```
in catch NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "str" is null
    at src.in28minutes.exceptionhandling.ExceptionHandlingRunner2.method2(ExceptionHandlingRunner2.java:20)
    at src.in28minutes.exceptionhandling.ExceptionHandlingRunner2.method1(ExceptionHandlingRunner2.java:13)
    at src.in28minutes.exceptionhandling.ExceptionHandlingRunner2.main(ExceptionHandlingRunner2.java:8)
Method1() Ended
Main Ended
```

Output after **running**(Exception is printed at the end)

```
Method1() Ended
Main Ended
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "str" is null
    at src.in28minutes.exceptionhandling.ExceptionHandlingRunner2.method2(ExceptionHandlingRunner2.java:20)
    at src.in28minutes.exceptionhandling.ExceptionHandlingRunner2.method1(ExceptionHandlingRunner2.java:13)
    at src.in28minutes.exceptionhandling.ExceptionHandlingRunner2.main(ExceptionHandlingRunner2.java:8)
```

Why order of printing the Exception at console varies while Running?

Answer (score 0):

Although System.out and System.err are both printed to the console, they are two different streams, and I don't think there is any requirement about which order they get flushed. `printStackTrace()` goes to System.err.

Comment: Yes, that's what I believe as well,But it's printing right so there must be some ordering thing as well.